# How to fetch Admob url without clicking on ads?

Tags: android, admob

I want to fetch ads url without clicking on it.

Is it possible in admob??

I tried various sources,but unable to get the answer.

Comment: If it was possible you would be able to open ads in the background and cheat the admob system. I don't think they want you to do that, so it's unlikely that such an operation is permitted.

Comment: is it possible to fetch url that's opened when we click on ad??

Answer (score 0):

in the logcat you can see from which address the ad was fetched from. maybe that could be a tip.